# Can I pass the reference of cudaStream to a function where it calls a global method

Tags: cuda

I am creating cudaStream in a host function

```
void callKernel(cudaStream_t* ptrStream)
{
    kernelDoesNotMatter<<<1,12,0,*ptrStream>>>();
    //Here i am not calling cudaStreamSynchronize
}
void host_func()
{
    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);
    callKernel(&stream);

    cudaError_t err = cudaStreamQuery(stream) //err == cudaSuccess?
}
```

Over here I am not calling cudaStreamSynchronize() after calling kernel in callKernel method why does cudaStreamQuery return cudaSuccess? Is it because we cannot pass the reference of cudaStream_t to another function? Am I missing something in this?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe because the execution finished before cudaStreamQuery?

Comment: i am not calling cudaStreamSynchronoize, so operations in the stream wont be executed.

Comment: cudaStreamSynchronoize is to *ensure* execution has finished.  kernel *may* be done before cudaStreamSynchronoize

Comment: so how am i suppose to check whether kernel is still working

Comment: are you telling me to do something like busy wait
while(cudaSuccess != cudaStreamQuery(stream));

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to do something like double buffering using streams.
I have a thread1 that continuously spins and reads data from socket and  dispatches it to another thread2 that invokes the kernel. I do not want thread2 to wait for the kernel to finish processing. So  that's why I am trying to use 2 streams, and queuing the kernels in them depending which 1 is not working so that I do not experience any packet loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cudaStreamQuery()` returns `cudaSuccess` if all commands on the stream have completed.  This means that in your example, it returns `cudaSuccess` because the kernel has already completed.

The purpose of `cudaStreamQuery()` is to allow you to write code that does other things on the host thread while waiting for the stream to complete.  You can do that with something like this:

```
while (cudaSuccess !=cudaStreamQuery(stream)) { doUsefulWork(); }
```

Note this is not an idle wait loop.

If you want the semantics of an idle wait loop, rather than having an empty `while` block, it's better to use either `cudaStreamSynchronize()` or use a `cudaEvent` and `cudaStreamWaitEvent()`.   The latter gives you more flexibility since you can wait on a specific event recorded (`cudaEventRecord()`) after a specific kernel or other call on the specified stream.

Comment: for the case that i mentioned above, can i use two streams?

Comment: I don't understand the case exactly, seems to simplistic in your example to warrant multiple streams.  However there's no reason in general you can't use multiple streams.  You can even have a stream wait on an event recorded in another stream (starting with CUDA 4.0), which is really handy.

Comment: I am trying to do something like double buffering (of kernels) using streams. I have a thread1 that continuously spins and reads data from socket and dispatches it to another thread2 that invokes the kernel. I do not want thread2 to wait for the kernel to finish processing. So that's why I am trying to use 2 streams, and queuing the kernels in them depending which 1 is not working so that I do not experience any packet loss.